# Copying from one filesystem to another while preserving file attributes

Tags: permissions, filesystem, copy

I am trying to copy the contents of one filesystem to another while preserving file ownership and permissions. I am currently trying

```
sudo cp -pR /media/myself/fs1/* /media/myself/fs2/
```

The copy job is still in progress but I am seeing that the first top-level dir on the target belongs to root, while the original belongs to my user account.

(Actually `fs1` was from another computer but user IDs coincidentally match.)

`fs1` is ext4 while `fs2` is btrfs. Both are external hard disks, auto-mounted by Ubuntu after I plugged them in.

How can I ensure all numeric owner and group IDs (including those not found on the workstation used for the copy job), as well as permissions, are preserved?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, since I am on a desktop system, I am now using Unison (with sudo) to do the copying, with the following profile:

```
label = Disk content migration
root = /media/myself/fs1
root = /media/myself/fs2
owner = true
numericids = true
group = true
dontchmod = false
noupdate = /media/myself/fs1
perms = -1
times = true
```

`owner` and `group` are options to sync owner and group, respectively. `numericids` tells Unison to use numeric IDs rather than user names.

`dontchmod` and `perms` instruct Unison to sync all permissions, including setuid/setgid (which is desired here, as I am preparing a replacement disk with a different filesystem).

`times` tells Unison to sync timestamps.

`noupdate` with the path to the original volume prevents Unison from accidentally modifying the original filesystem.